# R-Running ndiffs on each column of a dataframe and putting the results in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Basically, what I want to do is run the function `ndiffs` on each column of a `dataframe` and then store these results in another `dataframe` so for example if I have a `dataframe` of 5 columns I would have as a result a `dataframe` with 5 columns and only 1 row. In each column of the results `dataframe` their is the result of the `ndiffs` function applied to the same column index on the original `dataframe`.

I was able to do this by looping through the columns using the code below:

`df` is the original `dataframe` and `df2` is the result

```
dataframe
df2=cbind(" ",ndiffs(as.numeric(unlist(df[2])), alpha =0.05, test ="adf", max.d = 3))
for (i in 3:ncol(df)){df2=cbind(df2,ndiffs(as.numeric(unlist(df[i])),alpha =0.05, test ="adf", max.d = 3))}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this or not ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
df_2 <- as.data.frame(t(setNames(data.frame(apply(df[,2:ncol(df)], 2, function(x) ndiffs(as.numeric(unlist(x)), alpha =0.05, test ="adf", max.d = 3))), " ")))
```

Comment: If you are answering your own question, it's best to explain what your solution is and why it's an appropriate solution. Bare code without the explanation may not help others who have similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Without a complete reproducible example this is an estimate of what you want:

```
df_2 <- apply(df, 2, ndiffs(as.numeric(x), alpha =0.05, test ="adf", max.d = 3)
```

Which basically says save in `df_2`, the results of `ndiffs`(with your criteria) applied across columns (2 is the designation for apply to columns and 1 for rows)

If your matrix/data frame is pure, and you coded `ndiffs` right above, this should provide you what you seek without a loop and if the data is big it is much faster than a loop.